# ImageViews in RecyclerView not "weight" aligned horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

This is how it looks in the preview and on the device.

[image: Rows with different spacing]

The code for the row layout and the RecyclerView layout is as base as it gets

Row has a single ImageView:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width = "175dp"
    android:layout_height = "175dp"
    android:layout_margin = "4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id = "@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width = "0dp"
        android:layout_height = "0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf = "parent"
        tools:ignore = "ContentDescription"
        tools:srcCompat = "@tools:sample/avatars" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The RecyclerView (which is the only view in that fragment) is a Grid with 2 span:

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id = "@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width = "0dp"
        android:layout_height = "0dp"
        app:layoutManager = "androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf = "parent"
        app:spanCount = "2"
        tools:listitem = "@layout/row_dir_observer_secondary" />
```

I have no idea what is wrong, tried every gravity related layout setting, tried weights, but giving padding_start to the parent was the only thing that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `GridLayoutManager` as LayoutManager in RecyclerView, don't put fixed size width, because if you want each and every item of the RecyclerView has same width then GridLayoutManager Automatically divide screen width according to `SpanCout`, if you use width as match_parent.

So first remove hard-coded width value from adapter's layout file (example here is 175dp) and set to match_parent width in Adpater layout file.

Try this,

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "175dp"
    android:layout_margin = "4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id = "@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width = "0dp"
        android:layout_height = "0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf = "parent"
        tools:ignore = "ContentDescription"
        tools:srcCompat = "@tools:sample/avatars" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This kind of stuff is always obvious in hindsight... thanks!

Comment: Glad to know it helps, Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You've used hardcoded width in adapter, use match_parent, I think you're already using gridlayoutmanager with span = 2, so not need to change anything there.